# shell code to search between files and copy data from one file to another

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have two big files. file1 has data in below format

```
place u_RX_WR_SE1_LS { } R0 -place
place u_bank_LS { } R0 -place
```

file2 has data in below format

```
set inst RX_WR_SE1_PD ; add -inst $inst -cell PR ; place $inst  5.76    5305.84 0
set inst RX_WR_SE2_PD ; add -inst $inst -cell PR ; place $inst  5.76    5338.864    0
set inst bank_PD ;  add -inst $inst -cell PR ; place $inst  5.76    5371.888    0
```

I want to search 2nd field removing starting `u_` and `_LS` from file1 i.e `RX_WR_SE1` in file2, and if found in file2, for same match line copy `field $13 $14`  from file2 and add it inside `{ }` in file1.

The output should be in below format.

```
place u_RX_WR_SE1_LS { 5.76 5305.84 } R0 -place
place u_bank_LS { 5.76  5371.888 } R0 -place
```

Anyone who can help using SHELL?
In shell I tried

```
awk 'FNR==NR{gsub(/u_|_LS/,"",$2);arr[$2]="";next} 
{
for (i in arr) { if ($0 ~ i) {print i,$13,$14}}
}
' file1 file2
```

but this is not giving proper results.

```
place RX_WR_SE1 5.76 5305.84 
place bank 5.76  5371.888
```

Comment: Do you always have 3rd field in file2 ending with `_PD` or it can have other suffixes as well?

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    sub(/PD$/,"LS",$3)
    map["u_"$3] = $13 OFS $14
    next
}
{
    $3 = $3 OFS map[$2]
    print
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
place u_RX_WR_SE1_LS { 5.76 5305.84 } R0 -place
place u_bank_LS { 5.76 5371.888 } R0 -place
```

or if your input doesn't always have `u` at the start and `PL` or `LS` at the end but could instead have other characters before/after the first/last underscores, then this might be what you need:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    key = ( NR==FNR ? $3 : $2 )
    sub(/_[^_]+$/,"",key)
}
NR==FNR {
    map[key] = $13 OFS $14
    next
}
{
    sub(/^[^_]+_/,"",key)
    $3 = $3 OFS map[key]
    print
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
place u_RX_WR_SE1_LS { 5.76 5305.84 } R0 -place
place u_bank_LS { 5.76 5371.888 } R0 -place
```

Answer (score 1):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code; written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`, should work in any `awk`.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  sub(/_PD$/,"",$3)
  arr["u_"$3]=$(NF-2) OFS $(NF-1)
  next
}
{ temp=$2; sub(/_LS/,"",temp) }
(temp in arr){
  sub(/{/,"&"arr[temp])
  print
}
' file2 file1
```

***2nd solution:*** Making different field separators as per samples of Input_file(s) and making use of it with different Input_file(s) to get the required output.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  arr[$3]=$(NF-2) OFS $(NF-1)
  next
}
($3 in arr){
  sub(/{/,"&"arr[$3])
  print
}
' FS=' +|_PD' file2 FS=' |u_|_LS' file1
```

Comment: @Shreya, while running 2nd solution please make sure to copy/paste code correctly since its creating field separators before each file.

Comment: Just worth noting that that second script will fail if `u_` or `_LS` or `_PD` show up anywhere else in the key fields, e.g. `_PD` in `u_RX_PD_SE1_LS` or the second `u_` in `u_hulu_LS`.

Answer (score 1):

You have made a good attempt at it but need bit of more code to get the output right:

```bash
awk '
FNR == NR {
   v = $2
   gsub(/^u_|_LS$/,"",v)
   arr[v] = $0
   next
}
{
   for (i in arr)
      if (index($3, i "_") == 1) {
         sub(/{ }/, "{ " $(NF-2) " " $(NF-1) " }", arr[i])
         print arr[i]
         next
      }
}' file1 file2

place u_RX_WR_SE1_LS { 5.76 5305.84 } R0 -place
place u_bank_LS { 5.76 5371.888 } R0 -place
```

Comment: Thanks Anubhava, but In the above code again I could see that ```u_ and _PD``` are missing from the 2nd field. they should be ```u_RX_WR_SE1_LS``` and ```u_bank_LS```.

Comment: Ah sorry I overlooked that part. It has been fixed now.

Comment: Unfortunately question doesn't give full details. I have left a comment about `_PD` but answer is awaited. If OP has `RX_WR_SE1_XY` in file2 then 2 answers won't work as well.

Comment: I have made a bit more strict by adding a `_` but there can be other cases as well